# Method for Application Version on a Console Utility App

Tags: c#, .net, console

What is the best method for displaying major/minor versions in a C# console application?

The `System.Windows.Forms` namespace includes a `ProductVersion` class that can be used to display the name/version information set via the Visual Studio project properties (Assembly Information). As such, here is my current mechanism:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", 
   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName, 
   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductVersion);
```

Why is this part of `Forms`? Is this appropriate for a Console application?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

Also, you can still use the class, you just have to reference the containing assembly.  It's no biggie.

Answer (score 9):

`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version` is not the same as `Application.ProductVersion` (but may be good enough depending on your environment.

As can be seen with Lutz Reflector, `Application.ProductVersion` first attempts to use the **AssemblyInformationalVersion** attribute from `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` if it's present, and if `GetEntryAssembly()` is not null.

Otherwise it uses the file version of the executable file.

I don't see any reason not to use `Application.ProductVersion` in a console application.

Comment: Me too, but then looks like those methods are bad located into the System.Windows.Forms namespace, right?

Comment: Just a note for reference: If you are using `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]` in your `AssemblyInfo.cs`, `Application.ProductVersion` will return `1.0.*` whereas `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version` will return the actual generated version (eg. `1.0.6830.22375`)

Answer (score 1):

what about the following line

```
Console.WriteLine("FileVersionInfo::ProductVersion : {0}",
  System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileVersionInfo.ProductVersion);
```

Comment: This helped me, cause I needed to find out AssemblyVersion from library, not from the main app.